# How to create two completely separate window in java without using SwingUtilities?

Tags: java, window, java-9

**Disclaimer:** I know there is a similar question to my question but my question is different.

I am attempting to create my own debugger for a game I am creating. I want to create ***two windows: one window for my game and another window for my debugger*** where I can manage, view and change game variables when my debugger is on. I want to be able to simultaneously use and view both window. The problem is my debugger window is connected to my game window. When I close the debugger window is also closes the game window, this is a problem.

I **DO NOT** want to change the way I created my game window, I only want to change the debugger window.

This is the code I use to create my **game window**:

```
// main method starts
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Ultra Ball"); // create application window
        Game game = new Game(); // represents game class
        frame.add(game); // add the frame
        // set size of application window
        frame.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(game.getScreenWidth(), game.getScreenHeight()));
        frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(600, 500)); // set minimum size
        frame.setSize(600, 500); // for testing the game size
        frame.setVisible(true); // show the application window
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); // basic window operations
        Image icon = game.createImage("images/logo.png"); // icon
        frame.setIconImage(icon); //set the icon
        while (true) { // runs throughout the game
            game.setBackground(background); // set background color
            game.resize(); // resize game component
            game.move(); // move game components
            game.collisionDetection(); // detect objects collision
            game.debug(true); // debug the game
            game.repaint(); // redraw the game
            Thread.sleep(10); // pauses execution of game
        } // while loop ends

    } // main method ends
```

This is the code I use to create my **debugger window**:

```
// Debug class begins
public class Debug {

    // link classes
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private Game game; // Game class

    // JFrame
    JFrame window = new JFrame("Debugger");

    // Debug constructor begins 
    public Debug(Game game) {
        this.game = game;
    } // Debug constructor ends

    // create a debugger
    public void debug() {
        window.setSize(500, 500);
        window.setVisible(true);
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    } // debug method ends

} // Debug class ends
```

**Triggers the debugger:**

```
// debug method begins
public void debug(boolean status) {
    if (status == true) {
        debug.debug();
    }
}
```

***Thank you in advance for your help.***

Comment: *"Disclaimer: I know there is a similar question to my question but my question is different."* Based on what I've read, I would argue that that's not true; *"I DO NOT want to change the way I created my game window"* - What if it was the only want to solve your problem?  Which is more important to you? Avoid dictating terms to a problem you don't seem to not understand - it will help reduce your disappointment of the solutions

Comment: @MadProgrammer Limiting the solution space is common in software development (or any engineering task, really) and "it can't be done (with these requirements)" would have been a valid answer. Based on that information Ryan could have made the trade-off you ask about. Beyond that, assuming your double negative was not intended, _of course_ he doesn't fully understand the problem - that's kind of the reason why he asked a question. 

Comment: @Nicolai And, I have no issue with any of that - but if "you're having a problem", you should avoid "dictating" how you want the solution done and look towards finding one of more "solutions" that work - because the current approach could just be completely wrong for what is been sought - knowing when to let go of an approach is also an important aspect of software development

Comment: @MadProgrammer You are aware that he _already knew_ the other solutions, right? He specifically asked this question to find out whether there was one that met his specific requirement. This is _necessary_ to have enough information to pick a solution and potentially let go of the requirement. In other words, _stating the limitation was necessary_ to make an informed decision and you should not have critized him for it.

Comment: @Nicolai In your opinion (which I don't personally have an issue for) - What I asked was, which was more important? The solution or maintaining the current state? I simply suggested that they should avoid it, as it can provide a wider range of possibilities which they might have not considered

Comment: @Nicolai . *"You are aware that he already knew the other solutions, right?"* - How? Because they believe that there question isn't a duplicate to many others? With respect, how many times have you seen that written? The fact is, the core solution is a duplicate - but why they did need was a better understand of "why" those solutions didn't wok which is what I tempted to answer, so the question could have been better worded

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With this line you explicitly set your debugger window to close your app: `window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);`

> EXIT_ON_CLOSE (defined in JFrame): Exit the application using the
>   System exit method.

Try to specify different operation or even remove this line completely, so the default operation will be `HIDE_ON_CLOSE`.

Documentation and all available options:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setDefaultCloseOperation(int)

Comment: I use a while loop in my code so when I use "JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE" the debugger window keep on popping up.

Comment: So maybe line: `game.debug(true); // debug the game` should be executed only once before the loop?

Comment: @Ryan You should not be modifying the state of the UI (directly or indirectly) from outside the context of the Event Dispatching Thread. Instead of trying to use the loop to update the debugger frame, consider either using an observer patter or producer consumer pattern or a probe pattern to update the state of the debugger independently from the main game loop. The answer provided by kystain will solve the problem you're asking.  If this solution is causing you issues then consider providing [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates the problem you are having

Comment: I upvoted your code. I put "game.debug(true);" right above the while loop so "JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE" works. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

So a quick step through of the code...

`game.debug` is call on every cycle...

```
while (true) { // runs throughout the game
    game.setBackground(background); // set background color
    game.resize(); // resize game component
    game.move(); // move game components
    game.collisionDetection(); // detect objects collision
    game.debug(true); // debug the game
    game.repaint(); // redraw the game
    Thread.sleep(10); // pauses execution of game
} // while loop ends
```

Which seems to call...

```
// debug method begins
public void debug(boolean status) {
    if (status == true) {
        debug.debug();
    }
}
```

Which seems to call...

```
// create a debugger
public void debug() {
    window.setSize(500, 500);
    window.setVisible(true);
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
} // debug method ends
```

which explains why the debug frame keeps on popping up.

Two immediate solutions pop to mind, the first demonstrated by @krystainG would be to change `window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE)` to something more like `window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE)`

The next solution would be to change "when" and "how" `Debug#debug(boolean)` is called

The first step I would take is moving the `game.debug` call out of the game loop

```
game.debug(true); // debug the game
while (true) { // runs throughout the game
    game.setBackground(background); // set background color
    game.resize(); // resize game component
    game.move(); // move game components
    game.collisionDetection(); // detect objects collision
    game.repaint(); // redraw the game
    Thread.sleep(10); // pauses execution of game
} // while loop ends
```

The second change I might make is to only update the state when it's actually changed

```
private boolean isDebugging = false;

// debug method begins
public void debug(boolean status) {
    if (status != isDebugging) {
        isDebugging = status
        if (status == true) {
            debug.debug();
        } else {
            // Close the debug window
        }
    }
}
```

This will stop the method from reacting to state changes while the class is already in the specified state